# Why isn't the replace function working as intended?

Tags: python, replace, contains

I am trying to remove a common substring in a dataframe but I am unable to do it.

I am aware that the `replace()` method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

```
dfReviews['review']=dfReviews['review'].replace("This review contains spoilers, click expand to view.", "")
dfReviews['review'].str.contains("This review contains spoilers, click expand to view.").value_counts()
```

With these 2 lines, first I try to remove the substring and then I check if it has been removed.

However the 2nd line returns:

```
False    567333
True      16394
Name: review, dtype: int64
```

Therefore, the `contain` method is working as intended but the `replace` isn't.

Does anybody know why could it be?

Comment: You want `str.replace`: `dfReviews['review'].str.replace("This...", "")`

Comment: Hello @not_speshal that worked out great, thanks for the help (=

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for such problems with code. Also, is this about pandas? If so, add that tag. The two tags "replace" and "contains" are rather useless and can be removed instead. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].